# Normalizer of $ p $ group defined over $ \zeta_{p^k} $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $ (\pi,V) $ be a complex irrep of degree $ d=p^r $ for some finite $ p $ group.

Let $ \Gamma $ be the image of this representation in $ SU_{p^r} $.

Let $ N(\Gamma) $ denote the normalizer of $ \Gamma $ in $ SU_{p^r} $. Since the action of $ \Gamma $ on $ \mathbb{C}^{p^r} $ is irreducible then $ N(\Gamma) $ must be a finite subgroup of $ SU_{p^r} $ see

[Condition for normalizer to be finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570062/condition-for-normalizer-to-be-finite/4573236?noredirect=1#comment9625252_4573236)

Can we conclude that $ N(\Gamma) $ is defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^k}) $ for some $ k $, where $ \zeta_{p^k} $ denotes a primitive $ p^k $ root of unity?

That is, if we let $ \chi $ denote the natural character of $ N(\Gamma) $, then must all the values of $ \chi $ be in a cyclotomic field $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^k}) $ for some $ k $?

Example: The claim is true for $ p=2 $, $ d=2 $.

The only irreducible subgroups of $ SU_2 $ with order a power of $ 2 $ are the dicyclic groups $ Dic_{2^n} $, $ n\geq 2 $, which are all conjugate to
$$
< \begin{bmatrix} \zeta_{2^n} & 0\\ 0 & \overline{\zeta_{2^n}} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}>
$$

For the dicyclic case when $ n \geq 3 $, $ N(Dic_{2^n})=Dic_{2^n} $ is self normalizing. The final case to consider is
$$
N(Dic_{2^2})=N(< \begin{bmatrix} i & 0\\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}>)=< \begin{bmatrix} \zeta_{8} & 0\\ 0 & \overline{\zeta_{8}} \end{bmatrix}, \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}>
$$
which has normalizer of size $ 48 $, isomorphic to $ GL(2,3) $.
It can be seen directly that for all these dicyclic groups the natural character $ \chi $ of $ N(\Gamma) $ is indeed defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k}) $ for sufficiently large $ k $.